# Side by side structure values comparison?

Tags: structure, abap

How to compare structure values component-wise and display the differences?

Now I do it in a very primitive way:

```
DATA: tkomp  TYPE komp,
      tkomp2 TYPE komp.

WRITE: `Field differences: `.
DO 500 TIMES.
 ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE tkomp TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fld>).
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
   CHECK <fld> IS NOT INITIAL AND CONV string( <fld> ) CN ' 0,.'.
  ENDIF.
  ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE tkomp2 TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fld2>).
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
  IF <fld> <> <fld2>.
    WRITE: / `Component ` && sy-index && ` differs: ` && <fld>.
  ENDIF.
 ENDDO.
```

Maybe there is more beautiful way? Maybe there is something  like `CL_ABAP_CORRESPONDING` or something newer?

I found [oldie threads](https://answers.sap.com/questions/9974327/how-to-compare-abap-structures-and-display-differe.html), where they say *The Debugger uses the class CL_TPDA_TOOL_DIFF for analyzing differences*, hence is my follow-ip question: is it something that we can achieve in debugger?

I've never seen an applet in ABAP debugger that allows comparing structures against each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is actually quite okay. You might want to add `CL_ABAP_STRUCTDESCR` to get the names of the components for nicer output. It would also enable you to compare and analyze the types of the component's fields as well.

Unfortunately, there is no reusable class, function, or built-in method for that.

You will find the most precise comparison implementation in the class `CL_ABAP_UNIT_ASSERT`, method `ASSERT_EQUALS`. More precisely, the local class `DATA_DIFF`, method `DIFF_STRUCTS`, shows how to compare structures in a type- and nesting-tolerant way.

I can't speak for the class `CL_TPDA_TOOL_DIFF`. I've heard it mentioned before but we actually do not even have it in our SAP NW 7.52 systems.

I have also never seen a debugger view or plugin that would compare structures and display the differences. No idea where that comment comes from.

Answer (score -1):

There are code snippets at below, you can pass the structure in `cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data`.

```
 DATA: lo_struct TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,

        lt_comp   TYPE abap_component_tab,
        ls_comp   TYPE abap_componentdescr. 

 CLEAR lo_struct.

  lo_struct ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( p_data = lt_list_sum  ).

  REFRESH lt_comp.

  lt_comp = lo_struct->get_components( ).

  MOVE-CORRESPONDING gt_mov_grp TO gt_mov_grp_std.

  LOOP AT lt_comp INTO ls_comp.

    CLEAR lv_numeric.

    IF ls_comp-name(4) EQ cx_move.
      lv_numeric = ls_comp-name+5(2).

      READ TABLE gt_mov_grp_std REFERENCE INTO lr_mov_grp WITH KEY report_order = lv_numeric.
      IF sy-subrc EQ 0 AND
         lr_mov_grp IS BOUND.

        APPEND INITIAL LINE TO et_data REFERENCE INTO DATA(lr_data).
        MOVE-CORRESPONDING lr_mov_grp->* TO lr_data->*.
        IF <fs> IS ASSIGNED.
          UNASSIGN <fs>.
        ENDIF.

        ASSIGN COMPONENT ls_comp-name OF STRUCTURE lt_list_sum TO <fs>.
        IF sy-subrc EQ 0 AND
           <fs> IS ASSIGNED.
          lr_data->amount = <fs>.
        ENDIF.

        IF <fs> IS ASSIGNED.
          UNASSIGN <fs>.
        ENDIF.

        ASSIGN COMPONENT cx_currency OF STRUCTURE lt_list_sum TO <fs>.
        IF sy-subrc EQ 0 AND
           <fs> IS ASSIGNED.
          lr_data->currency = <fs>.
        ENDIF.

        lr_data->datum = iv_datum.
        lr_data->werks = iv_werks.
        lr_data->kunnr = iv_kunnr.

      ENDIF.

    ENDIF.

  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: you did wrongly get the idea, I do not intend to compare structure components type, I want to compare current **values** in runtime

Comment: @Suncatcher I understand, if you look at inside loop, yo get the structure's field value and compare structure's fields, if my post is valuable, please tick it as helpful answer.

Comment: this snippet is unrelated, non-compilable and non-readable, I have no idea what it is doing. Follow the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) approach when giving code samples